# Modify single Item of Laravel Collection without mapping every single item

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

I loop trough an eloquent Collection and I want to add the data to another Collection called "$tagCollection". If an entry with the same tag_id already exists I only want to increase the rating-column for the existing entry.
At the moment it looks like this. Has anyone an Idea?

```
$tagCollection = collect();

$entries->each(function($entry) use($tagCollection){
   $tagId = $entry->tag_id;

   //something like this
   if($tagCollection->contains('tag_id', $tagId)){
      $tagCollection->update ('rating' => $oldRating + 0.5)
    } else{
        $tagCollection->push(array(
            'tag_id' => $tagId,
            'rating' => 0.35
        ));
    }

 });
```

I also tried to use ->pull() to remove the Item out of the Collection and then push it again with the new rating but I also do not know how

Comment: I dont understand, you want to add 0.5 to a specific entry rating ? or also force the rating value of the rest to 0.35.

Comment: @N69S yes, sorry. 0.35 is for my example the base value. In the next run through I check if an entry with the same tag_id exists. If yes then modify this entry and add 0.5 (which is also an example value) to the existing rating for this entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do it with array instead of collection? For example:

```
$tagArray = [];
$entries->each(function ($entry) use (&$tagArray) {
    if (isset($tagArray[$entry['tag_id']])) {
        $tagArray[$entry['tag_id']] += 0.5;
    } else {
        $tagArray[$entry['tag_id']] = 0.35;
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow. Thats so much easier. I don't know why I got so fixated on Collections. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If the end goal is to update all the entries present in `$entries` that belong to a specific `$tagId`, then you can do this

```
$entryIds = $entries->where('tag_id',$tagId)->pluck('id')->toArray();
Entry::whereIn('id', $entryIds)->update(['rating' => \DB::raw('rating + 0.5')]);
```

And thats it.

Comment: I already tried that too. If I do it like you I get an error message with _Attempt to read property \"rating\" on array_.

If I do ```$specificEntry['rating'] = $specificEntry['rating'] + 10;``` nothing changes

Comment: The updated rating wont be added to $tagCollection. I also thought it would be that easy :(

Comment: @ProgrammingDude you're unclear on what you need to be done. you want to update the entries in `$entries` or are they in `$tagCollection` ?

Comment: From $entries I get my data which i want to put in an extra Collection called $tagCollection. When all data has been transferred I want to save this in my Database Models. 
I could save it directly and update the model with the same tag_id each time, but that would be unnecessary database calls, wouldn't it? That's why I want to first collect all tag_id in the collection ($tagCollection) so that they are unique, update the rating with every occurance of the tag_id and then save it in the database

Comment: Your logic is illogic. if the end goal is to add 0.5 rating to every entry that has specific tag id, then do it with a query directly.

Comment: Even if there are 20 entries with (for example) tag_id 30 in $entries and the data then has to be updated 20 times in the database? Thats why I wanted to change it in $tagCollection first and then save the correct rating in the database

Comment: and how are you gonna save the data in `$tagCollection` ?

Comment: @ProgrammingDude updated the answer to do what you needed in one query.